# TwitteR (R's Twitter API)- unable to acquire tweets when specifying geocode

Tags: r, twitter

I'm currently using the TwitteR package in R. I'm able to acquire tweets without specifying the geocode, however when I specify the geocode, I get an error message which I give below:

```
#setup permission using relevant API keys in setup_twitter_oauth

searchTwitter("dog") #this line works

searchTwitter("dog", geocode = '40.714997,-73.91623, 10mi') #this line doesn't work
                                                            #returns "Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : client error: (403) Forbidden"
```

The geocode I included is in New York City (I just chose a place with a high population density).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me if I remove the space in the geocode argument:

```
searchTwitter("dog", geocode = '40.714997,-73.91623,10mi')
```